# I am working in springboot and i have crud operation in my app. like if someone hits my crud operation using my ip address I need to get their name

Tags: spring-boot

I have tried like.

```
public void getuser(HttpServletRequest request)
```

How to get the user id of the another system when they hit on my request in postman?

If they hit in postman using my URL I am able to get their Ip address. But I am not able to get their user Id.

Instead I am getting only My username because they are using my IP address in postman to hit my url.

Comment: How would/are they be using your IP address?

Comment: What do you mean by **their username/user id**?

Comment: like if they are working under some domain and their user id is abc@gma.com means i am able to get their device name and instead of abc which is their user id .. I am getting my name as hostname

Comment: Please update your question and put some examples of what you are getting and what you are expecting so that community can help.